# How to convert Rabbit head_message_timestamp to Java LocalDateTime?

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I'm using RabbitMQ 3.7 and plugin [rabbitmq_message_timestamp](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-message-timestamp) that adds a timestamp when a message first enters RabbitMQ (for monitoring purposes).

This [timestamp](https://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmqctl.8.html#head_message_timestamp) is accessible e.g. via [RabbitMQ Management HTTP API](https://rawcdn.githack.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/v3.7.0/priv/www/api/index.html).

How can I convert it to Java LocalDateTime to find messages waiting too long?

**EDIT**

Sample watchdog code using @nicolae-natea tip:

```
public class QueueState {
    private static final int ALARMING_PROCESSING_TIME_IN_SECONDS = 5 * 60;
    private static final int ALARMING_MESSAGE_TRAFFIC_JAM_LENGTH = 20;
    private final QueueId qid;
    private int messagesCount = 0;
    private Long headMessageTimestamp = null;

    @JsonCreator
    public QueueState(
            @JsonProperty("vhost") String vhost,
            @JsonProperty("name") String name,
            @JsonProperty("messages") Integer messagesCount,
            @JsonProperty("head_message_timestamp") Long headMessageTimestamp
    ) {
        this.qid = new QueueId(vhost, name);
        this.messagesCount = messagesCount == null ? 0 : messagesCount;
        this.headMessageTimestamp = headMessageTimestamp;
    }

    public boolean isAlarmingState() {
        return (messagesCount == -1) 
               || (messagesCount > ALARMING_MESSAGE_TRAFFIC_JAM_LENGTH) 
               || isHeadMessageWaitingTooLong();
    }

    private boolean isHeadMessageWaitingTooLong() {
        if ((messagesCount > 0) && (headMessageTimestamp != null)) {
            long nowTs = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochSecond();
            long thresholdTs = headMessageTimestamp + ALARMING_PROCESSING_TIME_IN_SECONDS;
            return nowTs > thresholdTs;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the timestamp is provided in seconds(or ms: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-message-timestamp/issues/16) so you could  use:

```
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(seconds, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC)
```

on the other hand, you could get the current epoch and check against that, rather than converting timestamps provided by rabbitmq which should be something like:

```
long epoch = whateverThresholdDateTime.toEpochSecond();
```

Comment: thanks for help, additional links: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-message-timestamp/blob/master/src/rabbit_timestamp_interceptor.erl
http://erlang.org/doc/man/os.html#system_time-0

Comment: One more issue... once set `head_message_timestamp` (by plugin) is lost after rabbitmq restart. Do you have the same behavior?

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is the wrong class to use here. It is not capable of representing a moment, as it lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. Use `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, or `ZonedDateTime` instead.